# How to access public function of a WPF Form from another Form

Tags: c#, wpf

I found the solution of my question but its not working for me.

i have two WPF forms other than MinWindow form. i want to access public function `Data()` of form1 in form2. i have tried `(Application.Current.MainWindow as MainWindow).Data();`in form2 to access `Data()` function of form1, but nothing happened. Please suggest the solution

Comment: Is it mainwindow or form1?  Because if you do as mainwindow and it isn't that Type then you get null. I fact i'd expect an error. So is it calling the method but that method doesn't do what you're expecting?

Comment: The method exists in form1 not in mainwindow. And function does not executed at all

Comment: Is form1 even the first window opened?

Answer (score 0):

This is what I use when I need to call a Public Property, Function or Method. If you are using C# it shouldn't be hard to switch from my VB example.

```
    Dim winOriginalWin As MainWindow
    winOriginalWin = Application.Current.Windows(0)
    winOriginalWin.PublicFunction()
```

All windows open in a WPF application will have an index position associated with it which you can use to set a reference to that instance of the window. Let me know if that works for you or not.

If Form1 is open as the second window in the application I would suggest:

```
    Dim winForm1 As Form1
    winForm1 = Application.Current.Windows(1)
    winFrom1.Data()
```